# How can I animate a Mobius strip on local Z axis?

Tags: animation

I'm new to blender and I created a Mobius strip which I would like to animate by rotating on local Z axis. When I drag my mouse to rotate (R > ZZ), I get the effect I am after. When I animate with keyframes, the animation chooses a completely different rotation path to get to the next keyframe.

[image]

I will try to attach my .blend file as this is difficult to understand without looking at it.

[image]

How can I animate this properly?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding a driver to your z rotation axis? I would start by adding a driver on the z- rotation of your mobius strip. Create an empty object, and animate it going up on the z-axis or something, and use that as your drivers input variable. This should work if you only need to rotate on the z-axis.

Here's a video for a quick look at drivers: 
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57VGk_7I69M)

Aaand here's the docs if you really want to dive in:
[Blender Driver Docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/introduction.html#driver-configuration)

I took your mobius blend file and applied this method:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the solution the problem I was having. Thanks. I really appreciate your help.